# How to filter data with dplyr to retrieve NAs along with another value together?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
X      Y      
121    Yes
122    No
123    NA
124    Yes
125    NA
```

How can I filter out the "Yes" values from column Y ? I only want 'No' and 'NA'

My Desired output is this

```
X      Y      
122    No
123    NA
125    NA
```

I've tried

```
data2 <- data %>% filter(Y != "Yes") #But I lose my NAs with this command.

& 

data2 <- data %>% filter(Y %in% c(is.na(Y), "No")  #Doesn't work
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

```
data2 <- data %>% filter(is.na(Y) | Y == "No")
```

The line means "or". Your mistake was that is.na(Y) returns either TRUE or FALSE and those values are not in your data.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `subset` from `base R`

```
subset(data, Y == "No"|is.na(Y))
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(X = 121:125, Y = c("Yes", "No", NA, "Yes", NA)), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```